# Cases where TDA outperforms public benchmarks?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, topologies, algebraic-statistics, topological-data-analysis

**Precise Question**

What are some specific examples where topological data analysis (TDA) outperforms other models on publicly available data?

**Context**

When new ML algorithms are developed, it seems common practice to apply them to publicly-available data and provide accuracy comparisons in order to illustrate the novelty of the algorithm in a scientific way.

As a concrete example, consider the KDD cup references in this XGBoost paper http://dmlc.cs.washington.edu/data/pdf/XGBoostArxiv.pdf

Comment: TDA seems more like a marketing thing than actually useful. Why is it absent from all the big tools?

Comment: indeed...void of (public) scientific validation, it's hard to address this absence.

Comment: any updates as of 2020?

Comment: I'm confused about what task you are considering... and TDA isn't a single method, but rather a broad area that attempts to solve a variety of problems.

Comment: @Galen: sorry you're confused. Perhaps you could share a "success story" where an algorithm from TDA was applied on a public data set and outperformed a few standard ML algos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016, it seems difficult to concretely answer the question. Perhaps an ambitious, risk-seeking, grad student will provide more insight on TDA's performance as compared with well-known benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Comparisons between ML-at-large to topological data analysis (TDA) is difficult. This in part because much of what TDA attempts to do isn't even on the menu for most ML projects. One place (other than article databases of course) to look for examples of TDA is the [Applied Algebraic Topology Research Network's website](https://www.aatrn.net/), or [their YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/AppliedAlgebraicTopologyNetwork).

I am relatively new to TDA, and primarily focusing on persistent homology at this time, but I will offer a purported example. In a talk given by Renata Turkeš titled [On the effectiveness of persistent homology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7ENBfuRIl0) they describe a comparison of deep neural networks vs other techniques including classic persistent homology algorithm in predicting the correct homology class, and the latter was non-dominated by the deep neural network architecture.

Such comparisons only look at a small fraction of the possible models, datasets, and other choices. So arguments over the superiority of broad frameworks are often quite drawn out, and quite uninteresting in my opinion. **There is almost always a Pareto front lurking nearby** such debates. But if you want to get into the tradeoffs of the comparisons that were made in this particular case, I would recommend reading [Turkeš 2022](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.10551.pdf) to dig a little deeper. Figure 3 is the bar plot they showed in the talk.

Comment: thanks. the datasets they consider are toy datasets and provide good intuition. perhaps in the future we'll see comparative performance on more ml-specific real-world datasets (not toy).

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl For toy datasets we can analytically determine what the Betti numbers should be, and that provides training examples for supervised learning algorithms. On a real data set such analysis is unavailable, and thus such pristine training examples are unavailable. You cannot just look at conventional EDA plots such as scatter plots of a complex data set and just decide, "ah, this one has three 8-dimensional holes". On real data sets, the persistent homology analysis (as choice laden as it may be) will usually be the closest thing we have to the ground truth of the homology class.